# Testing file upload without form in phpunit/Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I am testing avatar photo upload functionality in a Symfony 3.4 app. The Symfony documentation assumes that this will be via a form. The page in question does not use form input however so I am having difficulty working out how to write the test.

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 docs-buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-upload" for="inputImage" title="Upload image file" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
            <input class="sr-only" id="inputImage" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
            <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Import image with Blob URLs">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Upload New Photo
            </span>
        </label>

        <div class="btn-group" style="margin-right:10px;">
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-method="zoom" data-option="-0.1" type="button" title="Zoom Out">
                <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;zoom&quot;, -0.1)">
                    <span class="fa fa-search-minus"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-method="zoom" data-option="0.1" type="button" title="Zoom In">
                <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;zoom&quot;, 0.1)">
                    <span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-method="rotate" data-option="-22.5" type="button" title="Rotate Left">
                <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;rotate&quot;, -22.5)">
                    <span class="fa fa-rotate-left"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-method="rotate" data-option="22.5" type="button" title="Rotate Right">
                <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;rotate&quot;, 22.5)">
                    <span class="fa fa-rotate-right"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="userId" value="6001777">
</div>
```

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a phpunit test written for a similar case, but where the input is a form. Is there any way to refactor this to test the page above?

```
  public function testUpload()
 {
  # Open the page
  ...

 # Select the file from the filesystem
 $image = new UploadedFile(
    # Path to the file to send
    dirname(__FILE__).'/../uploads/photo.jpg',
    # Name of the sent file
    'photo.jpg',
    # MIME type
    'image/jpeg',
    # Size of the file
    11832
 );

 # Select the form (adapt it for your needs)
 $form = $crawler->filter('input[type=submit]...')->form();

 # Put the file in the upload field
 $form['... name of your field ....']->upload($image);

  # Send it
 $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

 # Check that the file has been successfully sent
 #  (in my case the filename is displayed in a <a> link so I check
 #  that it appears on the page)
 $this->assertEquals(
     1,
     $crawler->filter('a:contains("filename.jpg")')->count()
 );
}
```

Comment: no PHP, no javascript, just HTML markup. And the HTML doesn't even have a form tag with an action. There is NO WAY to help you.

Comment: I apologise: I didn't write the app I am only responsible for (essentially black box) testing. No TDD went on in the production, which is why I am in this predicament!

Comment: find included js and paste. open web dev panel in browser and check network requests